# Spring DATA JPA: How to get success/failures while database constraint (Unique key violation) on saving a nested entity

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I want to **save** an entity having **one to many** relationship in specific case where the nested entity **throws unique constraint exception** without **rolling back** the transaction.

I want to save the nested entity which is still unique and get an exception for duplicate entity.

Example: Entity A has list/set of entity B type containing X amount of duplicate records. While persisting in the database if the record exists already in database I want to know which record failed to persist from the list/set and the records to be successfully persisted.

Below are some reference for the same problem but no concrete solution.

```
- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32691128][1]
- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15731297][1]
- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502279][1]
- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54343137][1]
```

Comment: A set can not have duplicate entries.

Comment: @theshadog there is nothing that guarantees any kind of relationship, let alone consistency between the equality used for the set and the unique constraints on the table  in which the set gets stored.

Comment: Yes agreed. Set can not have duplicates. Just used in example to say duplicate against database existing entries.

Comment: can you refer me to the solution for the above mentioned problem